# getName() encoding in Oracle 12.2 database embedded Java Machine

Tags: java, oracle, file, encoding, names

We are using the function File.getName() in java source DB object
in the Oracle Database version 12.
The "file.encoding" property is 'WINDOWS-1251'
We got the right file names in 12.1 (Java 1.6)
In 12.2 we are getting wrong characters ( Java 1.8)
The code is the same.

```
create or replace and compile java source named "JavaFileEncoding" as

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;

public class JavaFileEncoding {
   public static String getCyrillicFileName() {
   System.out.println("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());
     File f = new File("<Directory containing files with non-ASCII characters");
     File[] list = f.listFiles();
    for(int
       i = 0
       ; i < list.length
        ; i++
    ) {
      if (!list[i].isDirectory()) {
        return list[i].getName();
      }
    }
   return "";
   }
}
/
```

What is the exact encoding of the File.getName() result ?
Anything changed from Java 6 to 8?
The encoding OS server (Windows) settings are the same.. or maybe we should check
something else ? 
Couldn't find any mentioning in the Java Documentation.

Regards, Eugene.

Comment: Show the outputs. `File.getName()` returns a `String`, which (as far as you're concerned) doesn't have an encoding.

Comment: 12.2:  GETCYRILLICFILENAME()
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    i?eaao.txt

12.1: GETCYRILLICFILENAME()
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    привет.txt

Comment: And what's the default charset?

Comment: 12.2 "WINDOWS-1251"
12.1 - Charset.defaultCharset() not implemented in 1.6 yet
file.encoding = "WINDOWS-1251" for both

Comment: So to be precise there is no line "System.out.println("Default Charset=" + Charset.defaultCharset());" in 12.1.

Comment: `привет` encoded as `WIN-1251`, but interpreted as `ISO-8859-1` results in `ïðèâåò`, which is close to what you got, so there's definitely an encoding problem. However I don't think it's related to Java, but the settings on your Oracle DB or the platform you're running on.

Comment: Now seems to me so as well. The admins are comparing the DB and server settings. I will give an update.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Support reproduced the issue.

"cannot read cyrillic file names from RDBMS 12.2.0.1 java stored procedure."

They are working on it